# NUNIT test case for idbcontexttransaction

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, c#-4.0, nunit

```
I am writing  Nunit test case for the below. Here the IDbContextTransaction is from the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage library. Here the argument of DeleteDataAsync transaction is beling passed from the caller method and in the caller method it is written like using (var scope = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction()) this is being passed to this method.
```

Here i am getting the below error while debugging System NotSupported Exception.
Unsupported expression.GetDbTransaction .

```
public async Task DeleteDataAsync(IDbContextTransaction transaction)
{
    try
    {
        using (var command = transaction.GetDbTransaction().Connection.CreateCommand())
        {

            await TruncateTable(command, $"TRUNCATE TABLE MY_TABLE");
            
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        _logger.LogCritical($"Error occurred in DeleteDataAsync(): {ex.Message}");
    }
}

I am trying to write unit test case to cover the Delete data async method. Here i am trying to mock the transaction. 

 [Test]
 public async Task DeleteDataAsync_Error()
 {

     var transactionMock = new Mock<IDbContextTransaction>();
     var dbTransactionMock = new Mock<DbTransaction>();
     var dbCommandMock = new Mock<DbCommand>();

     **transactionMock.Setup(t => t.GetDbTransaction())
                           .Returns(dbTransactionMock.Object);**

     dbTransactionMock.Setup(t => t.Connection.CreateCommand())
                      .Returns(dbCommandMock.Object);

 }
Extension methods (here: DbContextTransactionExtensions.GetDbTransaction) may not be used in setup / verification expressions. May i know what is wrong here while mocking
```

i am unable to figure it out how and I am sure the below unit test what i wrote needs modification. Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: can i get some guidance on this question

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you have a repository layer and this method `DeleteDataAsync` is being called from an outside use case or service. I would recommend you to manage all the transactions states in the layer above (service or use case) and don't pass it as an argument to the repository method.

With that you'll have a more structured project with properly defined roles, clearer to understand and also you'll be able to test just the database command of the repository layer

Or if you don't have separate layers in your project, just manage all the transactions in the outside method that is calling this `DeleteDataAsync` and leave it exclusive to perform your query. For example something like that:

```
public async Task RandomOutsideMethod()
{
    try
    {
        ...rest of your code that have the transaction declared

        using (var command = transaction.GetDbTransaction().Connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            await DeleteDataAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        _logger.LogCritical($"Error occurred in RandomOutsideMethod(): {ex.Message}");
    }
}

public async Task DeleteDataAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await TruncateTable(command, $"TRUNCATE TABLE MY_TABLE");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogCritical($"Error occurred in DeleteDataAsync(): {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```